# Get keys and values of object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following object in typescript:

```
let parameters = { include: 'tags', limit: 20, published: true };
```

How can I loop through each parameter and get its key and value?

I need to do something with the key and value when value is not undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), perhaps with a `for-of` loop and destructuring:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(parameters)) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
        // ...use `key` and `value` here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys

```
 Object.keys(parameters).forEach(key => {

    });
```